# JQuery Mobile: Closing dialog reloads calling page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I have a Jquery Mobile app and a page within it needs to display the equivelent of a MessageBox dialog to present a message to the user. I get the dialog to display fine but when the dialog box closes the page that called it reloads. I just want the dialog to go away and not do anything to the main page that called it. This is a problem as this main page may have options already selected by the user and this refresh clears the options.

Here is my test code to display the dialog:

```html
<a href="/Dialogs/ListError.htm" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop">Open dialog</a>
```

The html for the dialog is located in a seperate page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html> 
    <head> 
       <title>Page Title</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div data-role="page"> 
                <div data-role="header"> 
                    <h1>Search</h1> 
                </div> 
                <div data-role="content"> 
                    <p>You must select a Location.</p> 
                    <p><a id="close" onclick="$('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button">OK</a></p> 
                </div> 
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

If it matters at all, I am using the VS2010 MVC Razor 3 mobile template which uses the _layout.cshtml file and has in it `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` by default.

Comment: I also tried changing $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false  to true just in case but it made no difference.

Answer (score -1):

try to add `return false;` to your onclick

```
<a id="close" onclick="$('.ui-dialog').dialog('close'); return false;" data-rel="dialog" data-role="button">OK</a>
```

else the default link action won't be prevented

Comment: Thanks for the response, but same result. The calling page is still reloaded.